# C# hmac hashing function converting to PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, rest

I am working on a rest call to an asp.net web service and was provided sample code in C#. I am having trouble converting the following function

```
 public static string ComputeHash(string hashedPassword, string message)
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashedPassword.ToUpper());
            string hashString;

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }

            return hashString;
        }
```

So far this is the draft php equivalent, is there anything specific I should be taking into account when converting between the two? Ignore any formatting am just trying to keep variable names the same for now for sanity. I can't seem to get these to come out to be the same.

```
function ComputeHash($hashedPassword, $message)
{
$key = utf8_encode(strtoupper($hashedPassword));
$hashString=hash_hmac('sha256',utf8_encode($message),$key,True);
$hashString = base64_encode($hashString);
return $hashString;
        }
```

EDIT
Thanks to comments below I am able to get both functions doing the same.

Now the issue I have is around the input message

In C# this comes out like this
"GET\n03 August 2022 14:57:27.569500\n/api/member\nuserName=tom.woodforde@redox-software.co.uk";

If I feed the same into the function below the output is different.

This is how the function is built in C# to generate the message

```
private const String _newLineChar = "\n";
 private static String CreateMessage(String method, String dateUTC, String apiModule, String data)
        {
            return method + _newLineChar + dateUTC + _newLineChar + apiModule + _newLineChar + data;
        }
```

In PHP this is my equivalent

```
function CreateMessage($method, $dateUTC, $apiModule, $data){
            $newLineChar = "\\n";
            $message= $method.$newLineChar.$dateUTC.$newLineChar.$apiModule.$newLineChar.$data;
            return $message;
        }
```

I can feed in the exact same string but get a different result from the encryption and I am assuming it must be because of \n

Comment: try `hash_hmac('sha256',utf8_encode($message),$key,true);`, the last parameter set to true, caused the return raw binary output.

Comment: I can't help you with your problem, but I can tell you that `utf8_encode` is [being deprecated and removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf8_decode_and_utf8_encode) in future versions of PHP because it is almost always used incorrectly.

Comment: Edits added based on lessmore that was helpful, I think this issue now is the way the message is structured as it requires variables to be split by \n in C# but doing the same string in php doesn't work

Comment: You can definitely [split on `\n`](https://3v4l.org/QbuTP), however that assumes you have that as a delim and not something else.